# Blog posts are not appearing as subs of Blog Page

Tags: posts, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, urls

I'm trying to set up a new blog on my company website and blog posts are not showing up as subpages to the blog page.

I would like for the url to all blog posts to read:

techmdinc.com/blog/post-title

How do I go about making this happen? Do I need to do it manually?

Comment: Is WordPress powering the main site or just the blog area?

Comment: The whole site.

Answer (score 0):

Set your permalink structure to:

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

This won't affect the URL's for pages, but *will* prepend `blog` to your category & post tag permalinks (unless you have set a category/post tag base, also on the permalinks setting page).

Comment: This won't affect non-blog pages?

Comment: Woops, typo. I meant "pages" not "permalinks" (answer edited). So in answer to your question, no it won't affect them :)

Comment: This would be on each individual page, right? Sorry, wordpress kind of bends my brain.